# I believe that I may be the father of someone famous. How should I proceed?

Tags: family

After much thought and investigations, I believe that I am the father of someone famous. I would like to get in touch with him.

I just want to have a conversation with him to tell him that I am sorry and to catch up with him regarding life.  I don't want his money.

What should I do?  How should I start?  Have any of you ever been in this situation before?

I know I screwed up as a parent, but that's in the past now, and all I can do is move forward and be the best man that I can be from now on.

Comment: Do you think fathering "someone famous" is any different than a "regular" person in some way?

Comment: @Erica: A famous person with an unknown father probably gets several people a week claiming to be their father, with peaks after every mention of the fact in the media. So yes, it will be very different. A famous person will be very much guarded and expecting a fraud or mentally unstable person, requiring a more careful approach.

Comment: A approve of use of a throwaway name for this question.

Answer (score 16):

Your assumption that famous people might be flooded with wacko messages and hence careful and possibly shielded by employees is probably right.

I don't think you should use public channels to contact him. Instead hire a lawyer to contact the child in question (or his manager), explaining why you think you might be his father, offering to be tested and declaring on your behalf that you have no financial interests whatsoever, just a personal desire to establish contact. The more "proof" you have, the better. Photos? Letters? Knowledge that isn't publicly known? You may include a personal letter to your possible son, explaining the same in your own words.

Once you ensured the message was received, the ball is in the child's court - he will decide whether he wants to get to know you or not. But this is the same for every long-lost father / child scenario, regardles of the "famousness" of the involved parties.

Answer (score 1):

It somewhat depends on the type of "famous". I'm good friends with a reasonably famous person but he is perfectly normal guy and easy to approach. Unless the "fame" comes with either a crazy fan base or the famous person is making intentionally a media circus out of his/her life, you can approach the person pretty much like you would anyone non-famous.

If it's one of the latter, you will have to go through their "agency", which can typically be found by a good google session. This will be difficult, since the agency will typically weed out a lot of communication that they don't think is genuine or relevant. You would have to make a really compelling case.

Answer (score -5):

You can contact him probably quickest via Twitter or his Facebook fan page.

Remember to not ask him about his money and fame.

Then, apologize and ease into the conversation.

Good luck.

Comment: If this person is famous, doing so is the quickest possible way to get ignored as a lunatic.